# New column for each element of the array

Tags: python, csv

I use the `csv` library to create a table of products.
In order to then import it to the site, I need that each characteristic be written in a separate column.

Adding a new row is done using simple loop:

```
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

for product in products:
    writer.writerow((product['price'],
                     product['vendor_code'],
                     product['characteristics']))
```

Adding a new `product`:

```
product = []
product.append({
    'price'             : price,
    'vendor_code'       : vendor_code,
    'characteristics'   : characteristics,
})
```

`characteristics` -  array that contains each characteristic as a separate element

How do I get the output file in this form:

```
190$    #0172    characteristic1     characteristic2     characteristic3
```

`characteristics` - initialization:

```
try:
    characteristics = []
    soup_characteristics = soup.find_all('tr', {'class' : 'product_card__product_characters_item clearfix'})
    for ch in soup_characteristics:
        characteristics.append(re.sub('\s\s+|\n',' ', ch.text))
except AttributeError:
    characteristics = ""
```

Comment: I think pandas is what you want

Comment: What does `characteristics` actually look like? How is it initialized? What do you see when you `print characteristics`?

Comment: Also, `characteristics` should have a default of `[]` in your `except` block

Comment: What does your final file look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unpacking the characteristic array:

```
for product in products:
    writer.writerow((product['price'],
                     product['vendor_code'],
                     *product['characteristics']))
```

Here is the code I tested:

```
products = [{
    'price': 100,
    'vendor': 123,
    'characters': [7, 8, 9],
}]
with open('test.csv', 'w') as fo:
    writer = csv.writer(fo)
    for p in products:
        writer.writerow((
            p['price'],
            p['vendor'],
            *p['characters'],
        ))
```

Here is the content of the `test.csv` file:

```
100,123,7,8,9
```

Comment: does not work. All data begins to be recorded in one column, even the price and the article

Comment: sometimes it works, but try adding name field
'name': ['Cabel (type1) Ubiquiti Networks']
The output will be incorrect. Any ideas why?

Comment: Where exactly is the name field "'name': ['Cabel (type1) Ubiquiti Networks']"?  And what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to build a list to write as an entire row:

```
for product in products:
    row = [product['price'],product['vendor_code']] # [price,vendor_code]
    row.extend(product['characteristics']) # [price,vendor_code,characteristic1,characteristic2,...]
    writer.writerow(row) # writes each value in the list as a new column
```

Comment: how so? what does it give you instead, and what do you need?

Comment: it records all the fields in one column, even the article and price

Comment: what happens if you `print characteristics`?